# Keep Different PhotonView In scene load

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I need to keep 2 objects alive in between several scene loads (Because my game principal's function and attractive is made with scene changes), so, I need to keep these 2 objects alive between scenes with a DontDestroyOnLoad Line, but it keeps throwing me the following error:

> PhotonView ID duplicate found: 1. New: View 1 on StartLabel (scene)
>   old: View 1 on PUManager (scene). Maybe one wasn't destroyed on scene
>   load?! Check for 'DontDestroyOnLoad'. Destroying old entry, adding
>   new. UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
>   Photon.Pun.PhotonNetwork:RegisterPhotonView(PhotonView) (at
>   Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonNetworkPart.cs:1017)
>   Photon.Pun.PhotonView:Awake() (at
>   Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/PhotonView.cs:264)

I need this to be all time alive because one takes care of some power and damage stuff, and the other is a time limit that I need to keep alive, so, when it finishes and gets its value to 0, kill the player and some other stuff.
Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Will You Please Describe more. Your One Photon is actually PU manager and other is Player? Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes, in PU Manager, but sometimes it appears in my Timer script too